# Is there any specific orientation when using ESE pod?

Tags: pods

Recently I got Handpresso POP.
At first I used ground coffee, but it makes huge mess on my office desk through whole brewing process.
So, I bought some ESE pods. It was way easier and cleaner than using ground coffee. Really satisfied.

But after that, I got two problems.

1. When I make espresso with pods, it's noticeably weaker than ground coffee. Actually, I've already expected that because of pod's paper wrapping, but it's way over my expectation.
2. When I close portafilter after put pod, sometimes water leaks from valve. After few tries with pods, I discovered that water leakage occurs when I put pod into pod adapter with certain orientation. When I touch pod's surface, I can feel one side is little thicker than other, and I got leakage when put thicker side down.

So, here's my question - is there are any specific orientation when using ESE pod? I heard that illy's ESE pod have certain orientation when using it, but I can't assure it's same with other pods.

Answer (score 1):

They never mentioned about the orientation in their [own site](http://www.eseconsortium.com/eng/). Both sides should work. My experience also overlaps with that. However, as this is an open standard, some producer may produce an ESE in a bit different way.